# Google Drive Picker API - Show folders and certain mime types files

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-picker

I've done set Google Picker API showing only image and .pdf files, but I'd like to set this showing folders, I've tried the following code:

```
function loadPicker() {
      gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
    }

    function onAuthApiLoad() {
      window.gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': clientId,
            'scope': scope,
            'immediate': false
          },
          handleAuthResult);
    }

    function onPickerApiLoad() {
      pickerApiLoaded = true;
      createPicker();
    }

    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
        createPicker();
      }
    }

    function createPicker() {
          if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
            //var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS); ... the mime type filter works only with DOCS
            var view = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS);
            view.setMimeTypes("application/pdf,image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,application/vnd.ms-excel");

            var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_DRIVES)
                .addView(view)
                .setAppId(appId)
                .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
                .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                .build();
            picker.setVisible(true);
          }
        }
```

With this code the Picker works, the problem is that inside each folder shows all type of files (Google docs files, zip, js, etc.)

These are the scopes used:

```
var scope = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
    ];
```

Can I show folders in Google Picker API and inside them only the files that I have set in the setMimeTypes() filter?

Comment: You should tag this with the language

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `.setIncludeFolders(true)` to your view. For example:

```
    var viewPdf = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.PDFS).setIncludeFolders(true);
    var viewPresentation = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.PRESENTATIONS).setIncludeFolders(true);
    var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            addView(viewPdf).
            addView(viewPresentation).
            setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
            setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
            setCallback(pickerCallback).
            build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
```